# SQL Query won't accept variables for ALL the parameters

Tags: sql

I have a database table with an event_id column and a scheduled_at column.
The query is called in php and is as such:

```
$columnName = 'scheduled_at';
$start = '2013-02-26';
$end = '2013-02-27';
// query to be executed
$sql = ( SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $columnName BETWEEN $start AND $end );
```

The query does not work when executed, however the following does work

```
$sql = ( SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $columnName BETWEEN $start AND '2013-02-27' );
```

and

```
$sql = ( SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $columnName BETWEEN $start AND $start );
```

does not work, but the following does work

```
$sql = ( SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $columnName BETWEEN '2013-02-27' AND '2013-02-27' );
```

Inserting the value manually makes it work but loses the usefulness of the function. Any ideas why it would not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to quote your variables, so that the SQL string that is created containes quotes around the date values. eg

```
$sql = "( SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $columnName BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' )";
```

Comment: Thank you so much :D! My entire project is coming together and this was the final test.